# Trying to run a mono bundled program, but getting missing libgdiplus exception

Tags: mono, gdi+, mkbundle

I am currently trying to get my C# program to run on Linux. Using mono on my Linux machine, the program runs fine. So I used mkbundle and it all compiled and such correctly. But when I try to run the bundled program on any other Linux machine I get this error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the 
type initializer for System.Windows.Forms.XplatUI ---> 
System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for 
System.Drawing.GDIPlus ---> System.DllNotFoundException: libgdiplus.so.0
```

This is the mkbundle command I used:

```
mkbundle --static program.exe --deps -o a.out
```

I also tried using mkbundle2 with no luck.

I thought maybe there was a way to specifically include libraries with mkbundle (like telling where to find libgdiplus). It should be linked in when I use mkbundle, but I guess it isn't because when I run my program on any other Linux machine (that isn't running mono), I get this error.

Both machines are running Ubuntu 10.10 AMD64.

Answer (score 6):

The mono 3.0 config file for windos has bad entries dor the libgdiplus references.

Change the two lines of the file C:\Program Files (x86)\Mono-3.0.2\etc\mono\config
as follows:

```
 <dllmap dll="gdiplus" target="/tmp/install/lib/libgdiplus.so" os="!windows"/>
 <dllmap dll="gdiplus.dll" target="/tmp/install/lib/libgdiplus.so" os="!windows"/>
```

Comment: I think this answer does not help the questioner, as it affects Windows. But for me it was very helpful and made me able to run Mono under Windows. Thanks.

Comment: i don't have a xamarin bug report account, can somebody report this to the mono team ?

Answer (score 2):

Extrernal helper libraries are not bundled in the executable, so you will either need to distribute libgdiplus as well, or use the -oo option to create an object file that you will link in a program together with the libs that you need. Of course you will also have to add a dllmap entry to map from, for example, libgdiplus to __Internal.

Note that if you just distribute the program generated by mkbundle as is, you're violating mono's free software licence, so unless, for example, you have a special licence from Novell, or you program is free software or you also distribute the object files of the app so people can relink themselves, you shouldn't use mkbundle.

Comment: Can you provide an example of including libgdiplus as a lib in the cc linker/compiler after the mkbundle step?

Answer (score 0):

If on your "foreign" machine you run this:

```
ldd a.out
```

You should be able to see what shared libraries it is expecting. You may need to distribute libgdiplus.so with your program or perhaps statically link in libgdiplus.a

Comment: Not true, gdiplus is not listed by ldd on executables obtained using mkbundle